# Linux GCC compiler options

Tags: linux, terminal, gcc, c

I have recently started using Linux as a tool for programing. In my book, I have seen that the GCC is used with 2 options: `-g` and `-o`. Now, I know that `-o` is to set a filename, but what is the purpose of `-g`? I thought it might relate to debugging, but also programs compiled without the `-g` argument are debuggable. So what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote from the manual: `Produce debugging information in the operating system's native format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF 2).  GDB can work with this debugging information.`  . I don't mean to be a RTFM guy but in this case, reading the manual section on -g will answer your question. As per -o, you're right.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answered my question. And i am sorry about not looking in the manual, I just forgot about it - Still a Linux noob :)

Answer (score 3):

-g option enables use of extra debugging information that GDB can use. Here's example of C code:

```
int main() {
    int x = 1/0;    
}
```

let's compile it without -g option and see gdb output:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:2:11: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
$ gdb -q ./test
Reading symbols from /home/mariusz/Dokumenty/Projekty/Testy/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/mariusz/Dokumenty/Projekty/Testy/test 

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x080483cb in main ()
```

And now with -g option:

```
$ gcc -g test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:2:11: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
$ gdb -q ./test
Reading symbols from /home/mariusz/Dokumenty/Projekty/Testy/test...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/mariusz/Dokumenty/Projekty/Testy/test 

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x080483cb in main () at test.c:2
2       int x = 1/0;
```

As you can see, now there is information about line with error.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to debugging:

(from `man gcc`)

> -g  Produce debugging information in the operating system's native format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF 2).  GDB can work with this
>   debugging information.

You can run a debugger on a program without debugging symbols in it, but it is like trying to find your keys in the dark.  Eg, you cannot set breakpoints:

```
(gdb) break 6
No symbol table is loaded.
```

That's a big hassle.